# invoking a SOAP webservice with telnet command

Tags: web-services, unix, telnet, soap-client

I came across a situation where I have to invoke a SOAP webservice (deployed in another server) from one of the production server manually and check whether everything is fine.

as these are all live servers there are no network tools like `wget`, `curl` and `nc` are available. I tried checking for a solution is google but no luck.

As a workaround I can write a java client socket and invoke the service but even that is not allowed in here.

`telnet` is there but am not sure how to make it work for my case.

Is there any other way to invoke remote services without these tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying few hours finally, I was able to invoke SOAP service with `telnet` as below

first open a TCP connection to the remote server as below.

```
$> telnet hostname portname
```

Once it is connected, frame a request as one of the below methods and paste on the screen and press `enter key` two times.

There are two ways we can call a service.

**Method 1:**  instead of mentioning endpoint path in `POST` header, we can give it in `SOAPAction` header.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "<endpoint URL from WSDL>"
Content-Length: <number of bytes you are sending in body section>
Host: <hostname>:<port>
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<SOAP Request payload>
```

**Method 2:**  mentioning endpoint path in the request header itself, so we can give empty value in "" SOAPAction header (it means request path itself is the Endpoint path).

```
POST /soap/server HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: <payload size>
Host: hostname:port
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<SOAP Request payload>
```

**Response:** Once the call invoked successfully, the response will be printed as below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: <response payload size>

<SOAP response payload>
```

For more information on SOAPHeader [check this link](http://blog.michaelhidalgo.info/2012/10/is-soapaction-required-httpheader-to.html)

***Note: Make sure the length of the request payload is correct before sending it.***

Comment: Thanks for returning with a solution! You made the internet a bit smarter today :)